# Is it fine the environment for data migration tool testing be the same as the environment where regression testing is done?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

We have a webapp which is an ecommerce site, and we have another web app (data migration tool) whose main purpose is to bulk upload data to the ecommerce site.

We then have 3 environments we can deploy these web apps to. One is production, one is Staging, and last one is test environment.

My issue is that on Staging, we do regression test of the ecommerce site there but they also want the data migration tool be tested on the same environment.

I think this is wrong and told them it could lead to us not being sure if there is really a regression on the ecommerce site or the data migration tool is the problem. They argue that we just don't do it simultaneously and it should be fine, which I still think may pose some problems or inefficiencies in the future.

I'm looking for arguments that can support my side so they'd agree that it'd be best to do the migration tool testing on a separate environment.

This migration tool btw is planned to be used around twice a month in case this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As software needs continuous integration testing, we need to ensure that the users who are visiting the ecommerce website during peak hours have a good user experience. So data migration is a key aspect when the configurations are changed/upgraded.

Regarding the environments whether data migration tool needs to be tested on Staging, below are the queries that you can discuss with the team:

1. Is the configuration of Staging Environment same as that of production?
2. Have the backend team that will execute the data migration script has a failsafe or backup of data in case the migration fails, than we can revoke the changes?
3. If we execute data migration on Staging than that should not impact the QA Testing Timelines and should not cause any environmental issues?
4. Also does the organization has required infrastructure to create a new environment and test the same within stipulated timeframe?

These are all important points those can be discussed and than the descision can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Data migration testing and regression testing are two distinct but important aspects of quality assurance (QA) testing and commonly used in a functional testing services companies.
The decision of whether to use the same environment for data migration tool testing as the environment for regression testing depends on various factors and considerations. Here are some key points to keep in mind:

**Purpose of Testing:** Consider the purpose of each type of testing. Data migration tool testing focuses on ensuring that data is transferred accurately and without loss or corruption from one system to another. Regression testing, on the other hand, verifies that existing functionality still works as expected after changes or updates. If the environments are identical or representative of the production environment, it may make sense to use the same environment for both types of testing.

**Isolation:** In some cases, it's beneficial to use separate environments to isolate testing activities. This can help prevent interference or conflicts between data migration testing and regression testing. This is especially important if data migration involves potentially destructive operations that could impact the existing system.

**Data and Configuration:** Ensure that the data and configuration in the testing environment are suitable for both types of testing. If the data used for data migration testing is different from what is used in regression testing and if there is a high risk of data corruption or other issues during data migration testing, it may be safer to isolate it from regression testing